# Automation anywhere: Acknowledging first email of the thread

Tags: email, rpa, chilkat, chilkat-email

Is there anyway that you can program a bot in automation anywhere community version, using the loop function (for every email), using outlook, to get the bot to check if there is an existing conversation in the inbox. If no history of conversation, then the bot acknowledges the email, if it does match a thread in the inbox then it files the email...I have googled everywhere and I have an inclination that it has to be driven by using the script options using messageid as a unique identifier. Any suggestions?

I tried vbscript mostly but I can't get the vbscript to even push out a unique id. I know it will somehow have to do with the loop until it meets or doesn't meet a messageid match but I believe the bot may be too simple to do this.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you Eugene, At this stage I'm just trying to get my VB Script to even recognize there is a email. I realized that even if you connect to the email and used a loop (using AA A2019) - it doesnt mean the VBScript is connected to the email server because whenever I ask it : Msgbox "Store id " & application.storeid (tried converstaionID / message-id) it returns blank. I have linked the sub to my run function. I then came accross this to actually try connect the mail using my server details but it still runs blank : https://www.example-code.com/vbscript/imap_markAsRead.asp

Comment: It seems the question is not related to Outlook, but it is about chilkat.

Comment: Referring to the vbscript not specifically chilkat. Not to worry I honestly don't think it's possible